# Not able to upload images in my answer

Tags: support, images

I am facing issues in uploading an image to my answer. I have cleared cache and cookies and tried in another browser. But the issue still persists. My image size is less than 2MB.

Here is my [error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bvo7.jpg):

[image]

Is anybody facing the same issue?

Comment: Clicking your image link gives an error that Imgur is overloaded. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: For me external imgur site is loading fine. But in the SOF, throwing me an error.

Comment: I recognize this. This has definitely happened before. Let me dig it up.

Comment: Every report of this I've seen boils down to some browser extension causing problems.

Comment: I don't have Norton, but McAfee. I disabled it and tried, but still, the issue persists. 

I tried in `Incognito mode`, it worked fine.

Comment: Before asking, please do a little search because this question is asked multiple times here in MSE

Comment: If worked in incognito, then the [tag:bug] can be removed because it is a client side issue.

Comment: @Sagar V, I searched using the keywords, `Incognito` mode solution was never posted.

Comment: @Sagar V, can't remove the tag 'bug'.

Comment: Not only by mcafee or norton extensions, but it may caused by any I repeat any browser extension or may the browser itself blocking the cross site script. What is there in the console (f12)?

Comment: It was working till yesterday. I have not installed any new add-ons to my browser since last couple weeks.

Comment: In that case, my Opera is a new installation, image upload should've worked fine. But didn't.

Comment: i have been notice earlier today in both chat and in questions that `https://i.stack.imgur.com` images were either taking longer to load or didn't show at all. might be related?

Comment: Disabling the anti virus won't help since you only disable its real time scanning, which is not the problem here. The problem is with a funky add-on the anti virus is installing "behind the scenes", and it's causing only trouble. You'll have to uninstall/disable the browser extension itself.